# Convert Streaming XML into JSON in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark and working on a simple application to convert XML streams received from Kafka in to JSON format

Using:

- Spark 2.4.5
- Scala 2.11.12

In my use case kafka stream is in xml format). The Following is the code that I tried.

```
    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("Spark Demo")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    val inputStream = spark.readStream
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      .option("subscribe", "demo_topic_xml")
      .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") // From starting
      .load()

    inputStream.printSchema()


    val records = inputStream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    //How to remove value column here while converting xml in to json?
    val jsons = records.toJSON

    jsons.writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", false)
      .outputMode("append")
      .start()
      .awaitTermination()
```

However the above code gives "value" column header as field name in the json output as shown below: 
`{"value":"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?><employees><employee id=\"be129\"><firstname>Jane</firstname><lastname>Doe</lastname><title>Engineer</title><division>Materials</division><building>327</building><room>19</room><supervisor>be131</supervisor></employee><employees>"}`

What I really need is only the xml payload to be converted to json without "value" column part. Look like I am missing something obvious here. Can someone please help me here. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Below solution working ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `org.json.XML` library to convert `XML` data to `JSON`.

Check below code.

Creating `UDF`

```
scala> import org.json.XML
import org.json.XML

scala> val parse = udf((value: String) => XML.toJSONObject(value).toString) // Defined UDF to parse xml to json
parse: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,StringType,Some(List(StringType)))
```

Defining `schema` based on `XML` data.

```
scala> val schema_json = """{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"employees","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"employee","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"building","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"division","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"firstname","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"id","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"lastname","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"room","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"supervisor","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"title","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""" // Define Schema of your xml data in json.
schema_json: String = {"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"employees","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"employee","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"building","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"division","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"firstname","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"id","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"lastname","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"room","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"supervisor","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"title","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}

scala> val schema = DataType.fromJson(schema_json).asInstanceOf[StructType] // Convert Json schema data to schema.
schema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(employees,StructType(StructField(employee,StructType(StructField(building,LongType,true), StructField(division,StringType,true), StructField(firstname,StringType,true), StructField(id,StringType,true), StructField(lastname,StringType,true), StructField(room,LongType,true), StructField(supervisor,StringType,true), StructField(title,StringType,true)),true)),true))
```

Final `Schema`

```
scala>
    inputStream
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    .select(from_json(parse($"data"),schema).as("emp_data"))
    .select($"emp_data.employees.employee.*")
    .printSchema

root
 |-- building: long (nullable = true)
 |-- division: string (nullable = true)
 |-- firstname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- lastname: string (nullable = true)
 |-- room: long (nullable = true)
 |-- supervisor: string (nullable = true)
 |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Writing converted to `JSON` data to `console`.

```
scala> 
    inputStream
    .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
    .select(from_json(parse($"data"),schema).as("emp_data"))
    .select($"emp_data.employees.employee.*")
    .writeStream
    .format("console")
    .option("truncate", false)
    .outputMode("append")
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```