# How to fetch column names from XML schema in SPARK SCALA?

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I have a requirement where I need to process a column in a table containing an XML. I am trying to convert the XML column into multiple individual columns based on the tags. I am using the spark_xml class to perform the same.
I have taken reference from question
[parsing XML columns from PySpark Dataframe using UDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64934508/parsing-xml-columns-from-pyspark-dataframe-using-udf)
but here it all processed in Pyspark, I need an equivalent of in SCALA.

I have come to the point where I can make the parsed column.
I need to explode the data and turn the XML tags into column names.
I need an equivalent of the below lines from that question in SCALA

```
df2 = parsed.select(*parsed.columns[:-1],F.explode(F.col('parsed').getItem('visitor')))    

new_col_names = [s.split(':')[0] for s in payloadSchema['visitor'].simpleString().split('<')[-1].strip('>>').split(',')]
```

Adding XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>
```

Output:

```
> # +---+--------------------+----+----+----+
> # | id|            visitors|_age| _id|_sex|
> # +---+--------------------+----+----+----+
> # |  1|<?xml version="1....|  68|9615|   F|
> # |  1|<?xml version="1....|  34|1882|   M|
> # |  1|<?xml version="1....|  23|5987|   M|
> # +---+--------------------+----+----+----+
```

Comment: can you add your sample xml & expected output ?

Comment: Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62379533/convert-streaming-xml-into-json-in-spark/62381019#62381019 might help you.

Comment: Have added the xml.

Answer (score 0):

Use `org.json` to convert xml to json.

Sample XML Data

```
val xmlData = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>"""
```

UDF Function

```
val parse = udf((value: String) => {
    import org.json._
    XML.toJSONObject(value).toString
  }
)
```

Schema for converted json data.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = DataType.fromJson("""{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"visitors","type":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"visitor","type":{"type":"array","elementType":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"age","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"id","type":"long","nullable":true,"metadata":{}},{"name":"sex","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"containsNull":true},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]},"nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}""").asInstanceOf[StructType]
```

```
scala> schema.printTreeString
root
 |-- visitors: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- visitor: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- sex: string (nullable = true)
```

```
 df
 .withColumn(
     "parsed_xml", 
     from_json(parse($"xml"),schema)
    )
 .select(
        $"id",
        $"xml",
        explode_outer($"parsed_xml.visitors.visitor").as("visitors")
    )
 .select(
     $"id",
     $"xml",
     $"visitors.*"
    )
 .show(false)
```

Final Output

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+----+---+
|id |xml                                                                                                                                                                               |age|id  |sex|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+----+---+
|1  |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>|68 |9615|F  |
|1  |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>|34 |1882|M  |
|1  |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <visitors> <visitor id="9615" age="68" sex="F" /> <visitor id="1882" age="34" sex="M" /> <visitor id="5987" age="23" sex="M" /> </visitors>|23 |5987|M  |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---+----+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but the schema of the xml is not fixed.. There might be few tags missing in real time and that's why I need to generate the schema in runtime like its done in the exmaple I provided.

Comment: Get XML schema in xsd format then it easy to generate schema from it.